# Jquery and Javascript combined. Code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

I have written the below code to display a selection of images within a

tag when a certain button is clicked on a page. The Jquery to hide the

elements on page load works, but the rest of the code does nothing. Can anyone help me figure this out please?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Create Array for images
    var vanImgArr = new Array("<img src='img\yvr\coalharbour.jpg'>", "<img src='img\yvr\lgbridge.jpg'>", "<img src='img/yvr/yaletown.jpg'/>", "<img src='img\yvr\lgbridge2.jpg'>");
    var sgpImgArr = new Array("<img src='img\sgp\elginbridge.jpg'>", "<img src='img\sgp\mbfc.jpg'>", "<img src='img\sgp\sgpdusk.jpg'>", "<img src='img\sgp\sgppano.jpg'>");
    var aniImgArr = new Array("<img src='img\ani\cat1.jpg'>", "<img src='img\ani\cat2.jpg'>", "<img src='img\ani\dog1.jpg'>", "<img src='img\ani\tandd.jpg'>");
    var absImgArr = new Array("<img src='img\abs\abs1.jpg'>", "<img src='img\abs\abs2.jpg'>", "<img src='img\abs\abs3.jpg'>", "<img src='img\abs\abs4.jpg'>");
    var clickedId;
    var idx = 0;
    //to display images
    function displayImgs(arr)
    {

        if(idx <= arr.length)
        {
            ('#pic').hide();
            ('#pic').html(arr[idx]);
            ('#pic').fadeIn('slow');
            if(idx > arr.length)
            {
                idx = 0;
            }
            else 
            {
                idx++;
            }       
        };  //button click close        
    }//displayImgs method close

    //on page load
    $('p').hide();

    //More info Action
    $('#more').hover(function(){
        $('#info, #info2').fadeIn('slow');  
    });

    //Button Click Action
    $(':button').click(function(){
        clickedId = this.id;
        alert(clickedId); //testing
        switch(clickedId)
        {
            case 'yvr':
                displayImgs(vanImgArr);
                break;          

            case 'sgp':
                displayImgs(sgpImgArr);
                break;

            case 'ani':
                displayImgs(aniImgArr);
                break;

            case 'abs':
                displayImgs(absImgArr);
                break;
        }//switch/case close
    });//button click close
});
```

Here is my HTML code to go with the above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title>Ricky Deacon CSIS3380-001, Assignment 2, Summer 2017</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
<table class="t1">

    <tr>
        <th width="25%" rowspan="3"><img src="img\rick2.JPG" alt="RD portrait goes here"></th>
        <th width="50%" colspan="2">Rick Deacon</th>
        <th width="25%" rowspan="3"><img src="img\rick1.JPG" alt="RD portrait goes here"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="subtitle" colspan="2">Photography Showcase</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="desc" colspan="2">Click the corresponding button to display images from your chosen category.</td>
    </tr>                   
</table>    
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="t2">
    <tr>
        <th>
             <input id="van" type="button" name="submit" value="Show Vancouver Images"/>                 
         </th>
         <th>
             <input id="sgp" type="button" name="submit" value="Show Singapore Images"/>                 
         </th>  
         <th>
             <input id="ani" type="button" name="submit" value="Show Animal Images"/>                
         </th>  
         <th>
             <input id="abs" type="button" name="submit" value="Show Abstract Images"/>              
         </th>              
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
             <p id="info"><a href="https://flickr.com/rick-deacon">Rick Deacon's Flickr</a></p>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2">
            <h1 id="more">More Info and Portfolio Links</h1>    
        </th>
        <th>
             <p id="info2"><a href="https://rick-deacon.pixels.com/">Prints For Sale</a></p>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<p id="pic" align="center">Image Goes Here</p>
```

Comment: Use $('#id').html to grab the value. In line 15,16,17

Comment: You have four arrays of images, each array is assigned to a button.  So, assuming someone clicks one of the buttons, what's supposed to happen?  The reason I ask is that there are remnants of code that displays one image at a time, but in your question you say display a "selection" of images.

Comment: Nikolas - Thanks, totally missed that!

James - an image from the appropriate array should display in the <p> with ID #pic.each time one of the buttons is clicked

J.Maria - Multiple idx's isn't necessary in this case, it doesn't matter which image from the array is displayed first

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten about the `$` sign on your code.
Your `display` function should be like this

```
function displayImgs(arr){

    if(idx <= arr.length)
    {
        $('#pic').hide();
        $('#pic').html(arr[idx]);
        $('#pic').fadeIn('slow');
        if(idx > arr.length)
        {
            idx = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            idx++;
        }       
    };  //button click close        
}//displayImgs
```

Also, shouldn't you use one idX for each array?

Comment: Thanks J.M, I added the $ signs, but its still not working. Also, multiple idx variables arent necessary as it doesn't matter which image from the array is displayed first, and for the purposes of this program, all arrays are the same size

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript refers to elements which don't exist in your markup.

First, there are no elements with the `id` of `"more"`, so the "More Info" action will never run.  Second, you are targeting a `button` element in your "Button Click" action, but I see no `button` elements either--just `<input type="button" />`, which you must specify using `$(":button, input[type='button']")` (Either one of those two selectors will work).

Comment: Thanks brogrammer - I added the more id to the h1 tag and that is functioning correctly now, I'm sure I had it there before, must have removed it somewhere along the line. I also added : before button, now the test alert is displaying correctly, but I'm getting an x where the image is supposed to display...

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting button tag while there is no button tag in your html. You should select input tag using $('input[type="button"]') 
but this might not be good practice at the time of debugging so you should assign input tag a name and then select them using
$('input[name="elementname"]').
Second .In "this.id" is not proper syntax you should use $(this).attr('id');